# webpack-dev-server doesn't seem to respect array.slice(0)?

Tags: node.js, webpack-dev-server

I have a webpack dev server. In it I declare an array that contains some data. In one of the end points, I copy that data, manipulate the copy, and then return the copy. Here is the code:

```
const data = [{ 
    title: 'Title 1', 
    history: [{startTime: 1}, {startTime:5}] 
  }, 
  { 
    title: 'Title 2', 
    history: [{startTime:3}, {startTime:7}] 
  }];

module.exports = () => {
  app.use(send.json())
     .use(connectRoute(function (router) {
       router.get('endPoint/:fromDate/:toDate', function(req, res, next){
         let copyOfData = data.slice(0);
         copyOfData.forEach((dataPoint)=>{
           let startTime = moment(req.params.fromDate,'X');
           let endTime = moment(req.params.toDate,'X');
           let filteredHistory = dataPoint.history.filter((event)=>{
               let eventTime = moment(event.startTime, 'X');
               return (eventTime.isAfter(startTime) && eventTime.isBefore(startTime));
           });
         });
         res.end(res.json(copyOfWorkflows));
       }
     }
}
```

The problem is that after the first request, my history of events is zero, even if there are events in the data that should match the filter criteria. From what I can tell, the `data.slice(0)` only gets called the first time. After that it just uses the `copyOfData`, which is not what I'd like to do.

I am attempting to have it store the original data, copy that data. Do my work on the copy, and then return the copy.

Answer (score 0):

`data.slice(0)` will always be the first element in the data array as it is not a mutator. Try assigning copyOfData to data.shift() instead

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. It has to do with the fact that `array.slice()` only produces a shallow copy. What that effectively meant was that although the arrays were not `===` they both referenced the same objects. So when I modified the history of an object in the copy, it also affected the original array (because they were both pointed to the same object in memory).

To fix this, I had to deep copy the array instead using the following:

`let copyOfData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data));`

This is not an issue with webpack or node, but rather a misunderstanding on my part about how `Array.prototype.slice()` works.